# Remove multiple files match in list in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to delete multiple files which match in the items of a long list.
The item in the list is like below and the list is very long:

```
['photo-1777.jpg', 'photo-4277.jpg', 'photo-620.jpg', 'photo-1078.jpg']
```

I try the following code but it fails to delete the files.

```
import os
path = "D://photo"
list1=['photo-1777.jpg', 'photo-4277.jpg', 'photo-620.jpg', 'photo-1078.jpg']
for x in list1:
    if os.path.exists(x):
        os.remove(x)
```

Comment: append the path you'll be fine. You're currently using basenames

Comment: `os.remove(os.path.join(path,x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do it without using os.path.exists:

```
from os import listdir, remove
from os.path import isfile, join

path = "D://photo/"
list1=['photo-1777.jpg', 'photo-4277.jpg', 'photo-620.jpg', 'photo-1078.jpg']

allfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]

for f in allfiles:
  if f in list1:
    try:
      remove(path+f)
    except:
      continue
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's works! Thanks a lot. but I don't understand  the usage of allfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]. Can yu explain more?

Comment: The variable path is the directory, "D://photo". listdir(path) yields all contents of the directory. The if "isfile(join(path, f))" part checks if each item is a file or directory, and only keeps the files. So if D://photo had a directory and a file, only the file would be returned.

Comment: You can also see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207973/19629009) to understand.

Answer (score 1):

When specifying file paths:

1. If the Python script and the files to be deleted are not in the same folder, you must specify the full path.
2. You should use `os.path.join` when dealing with file paths.

In this case, the problem will disappear if you edit your code like this:

```
import os
path = "D://photo"
list1=['photo-1777.jpg', 'photo-4277.jpg', 'photo-620.jpg', 'photo-1078.jpg']
for x in list1:
    file_path = os.path.join(path, x)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        os.remove(file_path)
```